# Will MPXJ Api calculate endDate automatically before writing to .MPX file?

Tags: project-management, ms-project, java, mpxj

I am using **MPXJ Java Api** to create,read Microsoft Project Planner files in Java..I found out a specific problem while executing the code..The code executes the file is created ...My question is will this API calculate the Duration,EndDate etc automatically based on the child tasks???>..because when i open the file in Project Planner i can see the End Date and Duration of Task1 . But when i print that before writing to that file it is shown as null..Any suggestion ??

Thanks,.

```
 ProjectFile file = new ProjectFile();

 Task task1 = file.addTask();
      task1.setName("Summary Task");
 Task task2 = task1.addTask();
      task2.setName("First Sub Task");
      task2.setDuration(Duration.getInstance(10.5, TimeUnit.DAYS));
      task2.setStart(df.parse("01/01/2003"));

  System.out.println(task1.getFinish()); //printing null
ProjectWriter writer = getWriter("sample.mpx");
      writer.write(file, "sample.mpx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that MPXJ does NOT calculate the end dates and durations based on child tasks. Microsoft Project does do this however, which is why you will see the attributes in MS Project whe you import your MPX file.